# How to load categories and its product in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Basically i am writing a PHP script in that script i want to load the categories by category name.When the category is load i want to load its product.For this purpose i have write this code but i cant find a way how to do that.Code is attached below

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                 $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
                 $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryName);

                $categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection() ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                    foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
                        print_r($product->getData());

                    }
```

i have also tried this code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$name = 'Gear'; //category name
$categoryobj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryproductcollection = $categoryobj->create()->load($name, 'name')->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
echo $categoryobj;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Please try below answer, i hope it will work for you.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get(Magento\Framework\App\State::class);

$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');

$categoryTitle = 'Your category name';
$collection =  $categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToFilter('name',$categoryTitle)->setPageSize(1);

if ($collection->getSize()) {
    $categoryId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();  // YOUR CATEGORY ID
}

$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
    //print_r($product->getData());
    echo $product->getName(). '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this

```
 // get products in category and all child categories
 //
   $_category=$this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($_categoryID);
   $_categoriesFilter = [
       'eq' => $_category->getAllChildren(true)
   ];
  $_productCollection->addCategoriesFilter($_categoriesFilter);

  // get product in single category
  //
  $_productCollection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => array($_categoryID)));

  // or

  $_productCollection->addCategoryFilter($_categoryID);

  $_productCollection->load();

         foreach($_productCollection as $_product)
         {
            // do something with $_product     

         }
```